# how to create flash button in javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, button, web

I want to create a kind of "flash button" in a web page. It just like the volume controller of windows operating system. When we click the button or the bar and hold it to roll down or roll up then we can change the volume .

Actually, I want to use it to control the speed of switching picture in a web page. For example, intially, the images will switch from one to the other in a default speed--image/5seconds. There is a kind of slide bar just like I described above, I can roll the button to left or right to control the speed of switching. How can I do that? Someone told me the flash may work, but I have no idea....

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best served to take a look at other people's work in this field.

i.e. http://www.clickonf5.org/smooth-slider/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [HTML5's range input](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.range.html). It gives you a slider that is made by the native browser.

You could easily do something like you want with code like this:

```
<input type='range' id='speed' step='1' min='1' max='30'>
```

Attributes are self-explanatory.

And in your script, you can retrieve the value like so:

```
speedVar = document.getElementById('speed').value;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fpzRP/)

Comment: There is no slider, how can I create the slider and use it to control speed? Please leave more details.

Comment: Make sure you're running a HTML5 compatible browser. The demo works for me on Chrome.